# Laravel: Resources with json field

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-resource

I am on Laravel 7.x and I have two models (`CustomerOrder` composed of many `CustomerOrderLines`) with parent - child relationship. Parent (`CustomerOrder`) model has a json type field among its fields.

*CustomerOrderResource.php:*

```
return [
  'id' => $this->id,
  'wfx_oc_no' => $this->wfx_oc_no,
  'qty_json' => json_decode($this->qty_json)
];
```

*CustomerOrderLineResource.php:*

```
return [
  'id' => $this->id,
  'description' => $this->description,
  'customer-order' => $this->customerOrder
];
```

CustomerOrder->GET request returns properly formatted data as:

```
"data": {
    "id": 11,
    "wfx_oc_no": 12,
    "qty_json": {
        "L": "20",
        "M": "30",
        "S": "20",
        "XL": "100"
    }
}
```

But for CustomerOrderLine->GET, the response is as:

```
"data": {
    "id": 15,
    "description": "test desc",
    "customer-order": {
        "id": 11,
        "wfx_oc_no": 12,
        "qty_json": "{\"L\": \"20\", \"M\": \"30\", \"S\": \"20\", \"XL\": \"100\"}"
    }
}
```

json field is not properly formatted. It seems it doesn't go through Resource class. Please let me know, how can I get this fixed?

**FYI**

*CustomerOrderLine.php:*

```
public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(CustomerOrder::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get it solved using [json cast](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting). The field was included in `$casts` array in the model.